# Is there a way I can set Font Height in Steema Teechart Graphics 3D?

Tags: c#, teechart, graphics3d

Is there a way I can set Font Height in Steema Teechart Graphics 3D?
The Closest I could find was tchart.graphics3d.fontheight , but it gets the font height , does not set it, 
so is there a way I can set the font height?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change only the FontHeight, because  you are only allowed get the FontHeight or FontWidth to consult their values. Therefore, if you want change the size (height and width) of font you must assign a value to font size as do in next lines of code:

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChart();
        }
        private void InitializeChart()
        {
            tChart1.AfterDraw += new PaintChartEventHandler(tChart1_AfterDraw);
        }

        void tChart1_AfterDraw(object sender, Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.Graphics3D g)
        {
            g.Font.Size = 25; 
            g.TextOut(100, 150, "TeeChartFor.Net");
        }
```

I hope will helps.

Thanks,

Comment: and also , I am developing an application which shows the graph of sample values collected, if the values are in the range graph has normal backcolor , but if they are faulty I want to set the chart background to Aqua color, I tried using tchart1.backcolor = Color.Aqua and I also tried tchart1.panel.color = Color.Aqua, but they do not change the background color.Am I missing anything? Thank you so much

Comment: @saumilpatel as Sandra Pazos posted in another reply, you need to do as I explained here: http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=12058&p=51829&hilit=backcolor#p51829

Answer (score 3):

The Chart of TeeChart to default have a gradient in its background. If you want change the color, previously you must disable the gradient of backround. You can do something as next lines of code:

```
private void InitializeChart()
{
    tChart1.Panel.Gradient.Visible = false;
    tChart1.Panel.Color = Color.Aqua;

}
```

I hope will helps.

Thanks,